# Find Last Row of Name with constantly changing names

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I'm really stuck on this one. I have a spreadsheet with thousands of rows. I use this code to filter them based off of product in the E column.

```
Sub IsolateCCENCE()
Dim Operations As Workbook
Dim Operations_Sheet As Worksheet
Set Operations = Workbooks("Operations for Macros")
Set Operations_Sheet = Operations.Worksheets("Operations")

Operations_Sheet.Range("$A$6:$AH$13108").AutoFilter Field:=5,      Criteria1:="=CCE" _
    , Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=NCE"
End Sub
```

Which works and leaves me with just under 1700 rows. Within these rows, in the A column, there are company names. Each company takes up approximately 20 rows. Each row represents a payment and has a corresponding date, in the D column. I need a macro (I'm assuming with a loop) that will then do the following:

1. Go through the rows, find the last row for each company
2. In that row, find the corresponding date
3. If that date is within 30 days from today, generate an email

Part 3 is easy. But Part 1 and 2 I can't seem to get. The data is always going to be changing.

Maybe it would be easier to have all of the data copy and pasted into another spreadsheet and then filter through every single company, find the last row (and thus the corresponding date)? But I don't know I would have a macro defined to filter through each company when the company names will be changing constantly.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are really asking for too much with very little details, doubtful you will find people to simply write an extensive amount of code for you for free

Comment: I'm just asking for somewhere to start.

Comment: After you filter by product, you could use Range.Find searching for each company.  Start at the first cell in the company column; `searchdirection:=xlprevious`; `lookin:=xlvalues`.   Using those arguments, .Find should skip the hidden rows and, searching from the bottom up, should find the last instance first.

Comment: Find the row number of the last *CCE* with `application.match("CCEzz", range("E:E"))`. If *CCE* is stored in a var then it would seem a simple matter to append *zz* to the var.

Comment: @pnuts, it's actually the opposite. The last row is the latest date. The first row is the most recent.

Answer (score 0):

If a specific company name in say F1 then:

```
=MIN(IF(A:A=F1,D:D))
```

entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter should give you the earliest date for the company named in F1, that if more recent than today()-30 (or less far into the future than today()+30 ?) you might use for your e-mail trigger (subject to other filtering etc).